# "delete" - restore native function not working for changed prototype, how then?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, built-in

if you change native function like this:

```
window.open= function (a,b,c)
{
    alert(2);
}
```

then later you can just

```
delete window.open
```

and it would restore original function, BUT:

if you change its prototype like this:

```
window.__proto__.open= function (a,b,c)
{
    alert(3);
}
```

then `delete` won't do anything =\ any ideas how to restore it now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you change `window.open` to something else, e.g. using `window.open = 'something else';`, then you're *shadowing* the `open` method from the prototype;

```js
// Looking up window.open (in the prototype chain)....
window.open;           // Found, result == 'something else'
window.__proto__.open; // Not accessible any more (shadowed by previous line)
```

After invoking `delete window.open` to delete `'something else'`, the original method becomes visible again, because it had never disappeared from the prototype chain.

But if you've modified the `open` method on the prototype, e.g. `window.__proto__.open = bogus;`, then you cannot easily restore the old method. So, to get the "open window" behavior again, you need to either keep a reference to the original method before replacing it,

```js
var original_open = window.open;
window.__proto__.open = 'bogus';
// .... whatever ....
// Now restore it:
window.__proto__.open = original_open;
```

Or borrow it from another `window`, e.g. using a temporary new frame:

```js
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(frame);
window.__proto__.open = frame.contentWindow.open;
frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
```

This whole idea is ridiculous though: You **should not break built-in methods**.

Comment: so after `document.__proto__.createElement = "bogus";` there is no more hope? :-)

Comment: @Owyn There are many ways to create frames: `element.innerHTML = ..`, `element.insertAdjacentHTML`, `document.createElementNS`, to name a few

Comment: @Owyn In chrome at least, if you delete document.__proto__.createElement it reverts it back to native or absent, as applicable.

Comment: @kbenson That is because `createElement` is not a property of `document.__proto__`, but `document.__proto__.__proto__` (the hierarchy is document < HTMLDocument < Document < Node < EventTarget < Object).

Answer (score 1):

delete window.open;

```
(function(func) {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
    // Intentionally set in global scope
    window[func] = frame.contentWindow[func];
    frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
})("open");
```

> open

ƒ open() { [native code] }