# Chrome Devtools console not working in certain websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing some studies in Javascript using Twitter website as example. In any website i can open Google Devtools and use the console to manipulate anything on the page, such as get DOM nodes, edit elements and so on.

For instance, when i open 'www.google.com', go to Devtools and type the command above :

console.log('testing');

I get 'testing' string showing in the console.

[image]

However, when i open 'www.twitter.com' and do the same thing, NOTHING happens. Nothing is shown in console, just an 'undefined' string as shown below :

[image]

Why this behaviour happens only on Twitter website ?

EDIT : Tried the solution proposed on 
["delete" - restore native function not working for changed prototype, how then?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159559/delete-restore-native-function-not-working-for-changed-prototype-how-then/21160069#21160069)

But did not work :

[image]

Comment: they have probably overriden the method `window.console.log` so that it outputs nothing.. (the `undefined` is normal, it's just the evaluation of the whole expression)

Comment: I did not changed anything, i just open Twitter and type the command ; you can test yourself and simulate the issue.

Comment: my comment says "they", not "you" ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Javascript you can modify your global objects, so it's possible for you to do something like

```
Array.prototype.push = function(element) {
  this[this.length] = 'blah'
}
```

Now every time you add a element to any array it will always add 'blah';

```
const myArray = [];
myArray.push(1);
myArray.push(2);
myArray.push(3);
console.log(myArray);
// output ['blah', 'blah', 'blah']
```

In the twitter website they did the same, although the code is minified you can see it here:

```
, Y = ["log", "warn", "debug", "info"]
, K = function() {}
, Q = ""
```

Line 1414 file https://abs.twimg.com/k/en/init.en.caa653749241467e7dbb.js

To make it work again, copy each line and run it on your console (credits for this solution to Rob W):

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(frame);
console = frame.contentWindow.console
console.log('it works')
```

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to restore the original 'console.log' function ?

Comment: Thank you, but i tried the example changing by console, and did not work... Still console not showing. Help please ?

Comment: using an iframe to get an original log function is pretty clever ^^

Comment: Thanks @Kaddath , but the credits are all to the answer I provided in the comments by Rob W

Comment: @FabioAntunes yeah i noticed Rob W is quite badass if you allow me ^^ you still found it

Answer (score 2):

If you type in just `console.log` (without any brackets), you can list the code for the log function on that website. Doing this on Twitter gives you

```
function (){}
```

Which is indeed an empty function showing that they've overwritten the default. By contrast, the same on google.com gives

```
function log() { [native code] }
```

Which is the default.

Comment: Ok, but how can i make the original console.log() work as default in Twitter ?

Comment: You'd need a reference to the original method, which I can't see anywhere. They've also overwritten `info`, but you could do an awkward version by pointing it to the error method. `console.log = console.error`