# Can Javascript access read-only references to native browser functions?

Tags: javascript, browser

Browser functions/objects like setTimeout, setInterval, JSON, etc. can all be overwritten by Javascript code.

However, in the same way that these functions are stored on the window object, I was wondering if there was a reliable way of getting a reference to any of these functions that would reliably be 'the real one'.

At the moment I can *reasonably* check if a function like these is the native one or not (`setTimeout.toString() === 'function setTimeout() { [native code] }'`)

However, if I find that the setTimeout function has been modified earlier in the code, is there any way to figure out a reference to the native function?

I have looked for read-only copies of the `window` object that would be protected, but couldn't find anything of the sort.

The goal for this is mainly to protect page behavior from some simple breakages due to code I don't control (say, browser extensions) tampering with native functions.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: `delete setTimeout; setTimeout(fn, 10);`

Comment: Would be lovely, but this doesn't seem to work, at least in Chrome 83. After deleting setTimeout, it becomes undefined and anything that calls it throws a ReferenceError

Comment: Not surprised, native refs ebbs and flow over releases. I swear [it used to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159559/delete-restore-native-function-not-working-for-changed-prototype-how-then). BTW, your "validation" is weak, i can make anything native: `alert( (x=>x).bind(0))`. You can dredge up an iframe with a fresh window, use a webworker, or run your script first and memorize a ref to the "legit" setTimeout... If anyone knows something better, please share.